# Start and Stop a process to find PID in Bash Script

Tags: bash, pid

I am given a program that runs until it is stopped using ctrl + c.  I need to find the pid  of this process and then output information like user time, system time, and total time using a bash script. It is my understanding that in order to do this I need to run the process and then stop it inside the script and after I stop the program I am able to find the information. I am having issues with stopping the process inside the script.

```
#!/bin/bash   

clarg="$1"

if [ "$clarg" == "cpu" ] ; then
    gcc -o cpu cpu.c
    ./cpu

   #This is where I'm lost and tried this out from  online but 
   #didn't work for me

   trap "exit" INT
   while :
   do
        sl -e
   done

#Commands to find PID info below.
```

Comment: You can run it in the background. Then the PID will be in `$!`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, this should do what you want (explanation added as comments inside code):

```
#!/bin/bash

clarg="$1"

if [ "$clarg" == "cpu" ] ; then
    gcc -o cpu cpu.c

    # Run cpu via time in background, get pid of time process
    time ./cpu &
    ppid=$!

    # Let cpu run for a while
    sleep 15s
    # Alternatively, wait for user to hit ENTER
    #read -s -p "Hit ENTER to terminate cpu."

    # Get pid of time's child process (i.e. pid of cpu process) and stop
    # it by sending SIGINT (CTRL+C); time will exit and print its results
    cpid=$(pgrep -P $ppid)
    kill -INT $cpid
fi
```

I assumed here that `cpu` is the *program* you mentioned.

Comment: @101001: if this helped your cause, please consider marking the answer as accepted.